# typing 'rails console' doesn't start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I typed this:

```
>rails console
```

and got this:

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
      [--skip-gemfile]        # Don't create a Gemfile
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]   # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db)
                              # Default: sqlite3
..
..
.
```

I'm following along the rails tutorial and got stuck on this.

I have rails 3.0 installed.

Comment: have you modified your bashrc (or bash_profile) file in any way?  I once had this very same problem after modifying mine to display the current directory in my command prompt

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Are you in the root path of your app when you type `$ rails console`?

Tip: `$ rails c` is a shortcut for `$ rails console`

Comment: no I wasn't, but it works when I am, why is that?  rails -v works outside the root path of the app.

Comment: `rails` is a system-wide available program. You use it to set up your environment using `rails new <projectname>`. In order to use rails commands specific to your application (like running the console), you have to tell it where to work - ie. running inside the project root.

Comment: Also ensure you are using the same version of ruby that the project uses.

Answer (score 41):

In case anyone else hits this, my symptoms were:

I'd deployed my application with Capistrano 3

I cd'd into my application directory, and rails console didn't work

Turned out I'd included the bin folder as a symlinked directory in my cap deploy, as follows:

set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

... and my bin directory in 'shared' was empty.

Two fixes:

- Ensure your linked bin directory has the correct contents (have a look inside your #{RAILS_ROOT}/bin directory for what this is, OR
- Don't symlink bin

I then re-deployed and it works.

Comment: You just saved me many hours of frustration. This was it exactly!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Clear and working instructions. It was extremely baffling for me since `bin` is actually empty and I was like "why would that change anything?" -- but it did. Thank you!

Comment: Missing binstubs can be (re)generated using `bundle exec rake app:update:bin`  (or `bundle binstubs <gem>` for a specific gem).

Answer (score 10):

I just ran into this same problem while upgrading a Rails 2 app to Rails 3.  When running `rails console` (or really `rails [anything]`) in my app's root directory, I would see general `rails new` usage output (as Blankman referenced in the original question).

The problem was that I had not removed the old Rails 2 scripts from the `script` directory.  After removing everything in the `script` directory and adding the `script/rails` file that is auto-generated in each new Rails 3 app, the `rails` command now works as expected.

In order to get the latest contents of the `script/rails` file, generate a new app and copy the file into your Rails 2 app that you're upgrading.  As of Rails 3.0.7, here's what's in this file:

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# This command will automatically be run when you run "rails" with Rails 3 gems installed from the root of your application.

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require 'rails/commands'
```

Comment: Thanks man. I ran into this issue and copying over a script/rails file fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem when I upgraded Rails 2 to 3 and was able to fix it by doing what Nick said, then also running `bundle exec rails console production`.

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 2.3.x the command is `script/console` within a given Rails application directory to start a Ruby console with the default Rails environment loaded into memory. Not sure if Rails 3.0 is the same or not.

Answer (score 2):

You need to into the project directory and command `rails console`
eg:

```
D:\workspace\>rails blog
D:\workspace\>cd blog
D:\workspace\blog\> rails c
loading en...
```

Answer (score 1):

are you in a rails 3 app directory?

do you have multiple versions of rails installed?

try checking 'which rails', and make sure this is a rails 3 executable you are running - that usage looks like rails 2.x.

Comment: which rails => /usr/bin/rails

Answer (score 1):

You are running the correct command (`rails console`), but you are most likely not in the working directory for this application. Change directory to the root of your rails application (beneath which you will find `/scripts`, `/app`, etc.), and the command should work as desired.

Note: Using `script/console` or `ruby script/console` is for earlier versions of Rails.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `bin/rails c` worked off my app root folder

Answer (score 0):

You need two gems "rdoc" and "rb-readline
After that add this gems in Gemfile and `bundle install`
Console is working fine

Arch-linux or Manjaro