# Why rails console did not fire up on ubuntu with rails 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rails-console

When type `rails console` under the deploy subdir on ubuntu, instead of firing up the console, it displays help message for rails:

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
```

However `irb` can fire up without error. Anyone knows why? Thanks so much.

Comment: Do a rails -v. I bet you're not actually running 3.1.3 from the console.

Comment: rails -v return 3.2.2. After bundle install, it show 3.1.3. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer here: [typing 'rails console' doesn't start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744567/typing-rails-console-doesnt-start)

You need to make sure that your current directory is the base directory of a rails app, because the `rails console` command needs to load the environment of that app.

Comment: I am in root. Now it return error saying js runtime could not be found.

Comment: Rails cannot find a proper JavaScript runtime, so you need to add one to the Gemfile in your project root.
Append
`gem 'execjs'` 
and 
`gem 'therubyracer'`
 to your Gemfile 
and run `bundle install` in the root of the app.