# Trying to run rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I am trying to launch the 'rails console' but it doesn't work, I get this message :

```
create  
create  app/controllers
  create  app/helpers
  create  app/models
  create  app/views/layouts
  create  config/environments
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/locales
  create  db
  ....
```

and no console is running? Is this command not appropriate ?

Update : I was running this command from the app folder !

Comment: This question is addressed in [question 3744567][1].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744567/typing-rails-console-doesnt-start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to be in your rails app directory

Comment: hm, what version of rails is this?

Comment: I think `rails console` should work, but you can try some of the other variants like `script/console`, `script/rails console`.  do you have a script directory in your rails app?