# How to call Rails console on server, if it uses Mina?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mina

Before implementation Mina on server, I called it with:

```
rails console
```

now I get:

```
-bash: rails: command not found
```

How can I call it now?

Comment: do you have multiple rails version in your system?

Comment: No, only one:
rails 4.2.4

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
mina console
```

Visit

[typing 'rails console' doesn't start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744567/typing-rails-console-doesnt-start)
or 
visit https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina/issues/279
for issue in MINA

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same problem and got:

```
bash: bundle: command not found
-----> Loading rbenv
```

`rbenv` is loading after the command was executed. 
So, I've created new task to ruan rails console and load `rbenv` before it.

```
task :environment do
  invoke :'rbenv:load'
end

task rc: :environment do
  invoke :'console'
end
```

`mina rc` to launch rails console